# Bootstrap container, grid rows width and a padding issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating my first bootstrap frontend, and I'm experiencing some issues which I'm not able to solve:

[image: row]

The row expanding to the whole width of the container, the max column width (12 units) will not extend to this width:

[image: column]

Further on, why is  within the container writing over the padding:

[image: padding]

Any hints appreciated!

I already tried to use container-fluid class, but the row seems not to get the max width.

Whole HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Snoo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

</head>
<body>  
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Snoo!</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reddit!</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">           
            <div class="col_xl-12">     
                <div id="content">      
                    <h1>Snoo!</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A chatbot based on a million reddit comments, quiet salty!</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

css:

```
#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%
}
```

Comment: col_xs-12 should be col-xs-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class name wrong `col_xl-12` to change class name `col-xl-12`

[image]

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks, I did type it by hand obviously. Thanks for saving me another 30 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a typo, try to change:

`col_xl-12` to -> `col-xl-12`

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove container from your coding. Then the row will have full width
2. your class should be `col-*-*`, but you used `col_xl-12`

The HTML Structure Will be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="/* Container or Container-fluid or Col-* */">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is wrong, container are never used insde row and row should always go inside container ... read documentation please before posting such answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif There is no specific Documentation mentions container should always be the parent of row. Am not getting anything wrong about this. Could u please explain or provide documentation link so that i can get clear idea !

Comment: @LaljiTadhani you can see, They mentioned the above example they used container
FYI: " Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes. "

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: simply read again please :) : *Bootstrap’s grid system uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content.* (it's the first sentence) then you can read *Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.* ... if this is not clear that the container should never go inside row, then am sorry ... you can also read : *We use the negative margin method on .row* : i i let you think about which class use possitive value in padding to regulate these negative ones

Comment: and if you read in the v3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/ : *Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.* and also *Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.*

Comment: and also here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/ .. written in bold : *Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are required when using our default grid system.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162023/discussion-between-pradeep-kumar-and-temani-afif).